# Azure Function to get image from Blob Storage stopped working on Local Azure Emulator (Azurite)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blobstore, azurite

Simple Azure function to get image from storage...

```
        [FunctionName("GetImage")]
        public static IActionResult GetImage(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "image/{fileName}")] HttpRequest req,
        [Blob("images/{fileName}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "BlobConnection")] Stream blob,
        ILogger log, string fileName)
        {            
            log.LogInformation("Get file from blob " + fileName + " length: " + blob.Length);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            blob.CopyTo(ms);
            return new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
        }
```

Worked just fine, than I faced an issue: can't start azure functions (Internal 500 Error - problem with blob storage).

Additional configuration parameter seems to resolve initialization issue:

```
"AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"
```

Unfortunately now function is not working when executed:

1. It logs access with required file name and size.
2. It stops for around 25s on blob.CopyTo(ms) line.
3. Error:

```
Executed 'GetImage' (Failed, Duration=26013ms)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: GetImage. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Inner source of Exception: Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.Download(...
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Connected to Azurite with Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. No issues there.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4915 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.14.0.19631

Exception thrown by: blob.CopyTo(ms):

Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.

Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Headers:

Server: Azurite-Blob/3.20.1

x-ms-creation-time: Wed, 30 Nov 2022 12:55:17 GMT

ETag: "0x1D64FE85292CAC0"

x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob

x-ms-lease-state: available

x-ms-lease-status: unlocked

x-ms-client-request-id: 6e6dff50-8c8b-4ccd-bb76-e9b460008293

x-ms-request-id: 91976feb-4421-47a3-9a0e-16a26dc6ad70

x-ms-version: 2021-10-04

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Date: Thu, 15 Dec 2022 08:46:32 GMT

x-ms-server-encrypted: true

x-ms-blob-content-md5: 3KQmtVIakH8iR9D9PlFbSg==

Connection: keep-alive

Keep-Alive: REDACTED

Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Nov 2022 12:55:17 GMT

Content-Length: 18304

Content-Type: image/jpeg

Content-Range: bytes 0-18303/18304

Content-MD5: 3KQmtVIakH8iR9D9PlFbSg==

Content-Disposition:

at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.Download(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable`1 timeout, String range, String leaseId, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentMD5, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentCRC64, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, Nullable`1 encryptionAlgorithm, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, String ifMatch, String ifNoneMatch, String ifTags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartDownloadAsync(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, Int64 startOffset, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadStreamingInternal(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, IProgress`1 progressHandler, String operationName, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.<>c__DisplayClass92_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

at Azure.Storage.LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream`1.DownloadInternal(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Storage.LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream`1.ReadInternal(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](Task`1 task) at Azure.Storage.LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream`1.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
at StandardFunctions.BloobFunctions.GetImage(HttpRequest req, Stream blob, ILogger log, String fileName) in C:\Dev\StandardFunctions\BloobFunctions.cs:line 39

Comment: add the rest of that inner exception to your question please

Answer (score 0):

Fresh installation of OS and VS. The same code with the same configuration is working just fine :/